# NoClassDefFoundError: java.applet.Applet.... Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I have the next line of code:

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
    .load(R.drawable.image1)
    .resize(100,500)
    .into(imageView1);
```

And i have the Exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.applet.Applet at
>   com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.Session.setAppletInstance
>   (Session.java:88) at
>   com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.(Picasso.java)

I copy de Picasso.jar and put it in the libs folder, then go to property of the project, add jar in library view and checked nn the export view. Dont know what can i do...

Comment: Your IDE  use eclipse or android studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem seems to be related with your antivirus software. It may be modifiying your downloaded jar (because it think it is an applet). Please disable your antivirus, and try again.

Check this: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2107445?start=0